# ReturnUrl has no value, ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've faced some problem recently and couldn't find the solution. I'm working on SportsStore from Adam Freeman's book Pro MVC 4. Look at this please:

I have a View called Index:

```
@model WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel
.
.
.
<p align="center" class="actionButtons">
    <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Kontynuuj zakupy</a>
</p>
```

CartController:

```
{
    public class CartController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public CartController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(new CartIndexViewModel
            {
                Cart = GetCart(),
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            });
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int productID, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productID);
            if (product != null)
            {
                GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { url = returnUrl });
        }

        public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart(int productId, string returnUrl)
        {
            Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
            if (product != null)
            {
                GetCart().RemoveLine(product);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { url = returnUrl });
        }

        private Cart GetCart()
        {
            Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                Session["Cart"] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }

    }
}
```

ProductSummary View:

```
@model Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="item">
    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    @Model.Description
     @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
        <input type ="submit" value="+ Dodaj do koszyka"/>
    }
    <h4>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>
```

and CartIndexModelView:

```
public class CartIndexViewModel
{
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And my problem is actually that my `<a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Kontynuuj zakupy</a>`
returns empty `<a>KontunuujZakupy</a>` Html, which I guess means that `@Model.ReturnUrl` doesn't get any value at all. I couldn't figure out why because i am begginer, would You mind to give me a clue about that? Thanks.
//edit
"Kontynuuj zakupy" means Continue Shopping :)

Comment: I think `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { url = returnUrl });` should be `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });` in your addtocart and removefromcart ar's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index action looks like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl) { ... }
```

It takes the parameter of `returnUrl` and insert that into the model which you return. If you browse to your website without specifying a return URL, it will be blank, for example:

```
http://localhost:1234
http://localhost:1234/Home/Index
```

Try passing a parameter like this:

```
http://localhost:1234?returnUrl=xxxx
http://localhost:1234/Home/Index?returnUrl=xxxx
```

Notice that the parameter name matches the index action. So in your `AddToCart` and `RemoveFromCart` actions, you need to change the name of the parameter from `url` to `returnUrl`.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the last line of your **AddToCart** action to:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
```